# Есть ли существительное, образованное от глагола "бродить"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Есть ли существительное "броденья" (от глагола "бродить") или какое-то подобное существительное?

Answer (score 4):

От глагола  брести/бродить со значением "двигаться, скитаться" не образуется существительное брожение. Лучше сказать "блуждания".

БРОЖЕНИЕ  1. Процесс расщепления органических веществ под действием микроорганизмов или их ферментов (как способ приготовления каких-л. продуктов или показатель их порчи). Молочно-кислое, спиртовое  2. Массовое проявление недовольства; волнение. Политическое б.

Примечание. Речь идет о современном значении этого слова.

Answer (score 2):

Брождение (ходить - хождение, водить - вождение) - по лесу, по незнакомому городу и т.п. Встречаются и литературные примеры.

```
Подошва у них отвалилась через три дня после брождения по лесу.
```

А. Г. Ивакин, «7 дней в июне»

Answer (score 0):

— Странно, почему-то никто не упомянул слово "брод".
Или я чего путаю, но всегда считал, что брод, сброд (сходка), бредень, бродвей (как место для гуляний) - имеют общего предка...  (также возможно и "бред")

> Там ступа с Бабою-Ягой идёт-бредёт сама собой.

Есть и у современных авторов:

> Я бреду, как в бреду – ни тверёз, ни хмельной
>   [От расстройства души и от водки.](https://www.stihi.ru/2012/12/03/8249)

Также есть и у Высоцкого:

> Но на происки и бредни
>   Сети есть у нас и бредни —
>   [И не испортят нам обедни
>   Злые происки врагов!](http://www.bards.ru/archives/part.php?id=19107)

Answer (score 0):

Слово *брождение* обнаружилось в [**словаре русского языка XVIII века**](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/02/sl214304.htm?cmd=p&istext=1):

БРОЖЕ́НИЕ(2) (-ье), (*един*.) **БРОЖДЕНИЕ**, я, *ср*. и БРОД, а, *м. **Хим.*** Ферментациею или тихим брожением от соли и земли очищенная вода к варению чая бывает очюнь вкусна. Прим. Вед. 1735 78. Нѣкоторые вырѣзывают в арбузах и дынях ямки, которыя начиняют изюмом: от чего произходит такой же почти брод, какой, бывает в молодом винѣ. Георги ОН II 80.

---

Но обнаружилось "брождение" и в [**Викисловаре**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (с примером):
**брожде́ние**
Действие по значению гл. бродить (ходить) ◆ Купил на вахту берцы местного производства. Подошва у них отвалилась через три дня после брождения по лесу. А. Г. Ивакин, «7 дней в июне».

Нашлись и другие (вполне к месту, как мне кажется) примеры использования.

*Максимумом ее возможностей было **брождение** а-ля Сусанин, и в этом **брождении** поляками были бы не кто иные, как дядя и тетя* (Бризин Корпс. Ничто).

*Краем глаза Пересвет заметил, как Бажен Нежданович принялся бродить по комнате. И пускай он заметил это краем глаза, **брождение** сторожа притягивало к себе весь глаз целиком. В нем было что-то ненормальное* (М. Злобин. Белая Рать).

И даже слово "броденье" нашлось (тоже вроде вполне к месту, хоть и нет его в словарях):

*У утра впереди не день —

А много дней в застывшем злате.

**Броденье** в омутах закатных...*
Д. Воронкова

Думаю, что эти словечки — как неологизмы — имеют право на жизнь.